# Problemas con una consulta laravel no puedo mostrar datos en un formulario

Tags: laravel

El problema que tengo es que cuando llamo la variable datos en el formulario de mi vista me tira este error Property [id_org] does not exist on this collection instance. (0) pero creo que mi error esta en el id que me identifica los datos en un datatable pero no se como podria resolver este problema por que realize un dd de datos dd($datos) y si me trae los datos pero no se por que ala hora de llamar los campos en el formulario me tira ese error

```
public static function organizar_eliminar_get($id)
        {

            $organizadores = organizador::find($id);

            $datos =\DB::table('organizador_tareas')
                ->join('unidades', 'unidades.id', '=', 'organizador_tareas.unidad')
                ->join('gerencia', 'gerencia.id', '=', 'organizador_tareas.gerencia')
                ->join('actividades', 'actividades.id', '=', 'organizador_tareas.actividad')
                ->join('años_trabajo', 'años_trabajo.id', '=', 'organizador_tareas.ano')
                ->select('unidades.unidad','gerencia.ga','años_trabajo.anos_trabajo','actividades.id','actividades.ao','organizador_tareas.id as id_org')
                ->get();

            return \View::make('organizar_eliminar')->with([
                'organizadores' => $organizadores,
                'datos' => $datos,
                'contador' => 0

            ]);
        }
```

en esta parte esta el input donde llamo la variable

```
        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('id', 'Id:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
 <div class="col-lg-10">
{!! Form::text('id',$datos->id_org, ['readonly'=>'true'], $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la variable data? no la veo en ninguna parte.

Comment: perdon $datos es la variable que me almacena todos los datos

Comment: Muéstranos lo que contiene la variable en mención, edita la pregunta y agrega dicha información.

Comment: datos me trae  un array:5[ ]

Comment: ahi si me trae los datos pero no se si es que los tengo que mostrar con un forcheach para que me lo recorra o como podria hacer para mostrar solo los datos que quiero que me muestre en el formulario

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que `get()` trae una colección, o sea que TIENES que iterar a través de lo que entrega. Te invito a leer la documentación de Laravel y a utilizar relaciones para evitar esas consultas enredadas que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

La documentacion dice:

> For Eloquent methods like all and get which retrieve multiple results,
>   an instance of  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection will be
>   returned. The Collection class provides a variety of helpful methods
>   for working with your Eloquent results.

El metodo get() de Eloquent te trae una coleccion y tienes que iterar esa coleccion para obtener los datos que deseas.

En tu vista puedes iterar esa coleccion:

```
    @foreach($datos as $dato)
       <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('id', 'Id:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'])!!}
          <div class="col-lg-10">
              {!! Form::text('id',$dato->id_org, ['readonly'=>'true'], $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}
                 </div>
       </div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: el problema es que hacer el foreach ahi me tira repetidos todos los input si me trae los datos pero los input me los repite y no aparecen los datos en un solo input si no que en diferentes